# Как выповнять по центру P с CSS?

Tags: html

Немного перефразирую вопрос в заголовке:

Как достичь такого же эффекта используя только CSS без использования тега `<center>`?

```
<center><p>это строка</p></center>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82968/discussion-on-question-by-html80lvl-----p--css).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**text-align:center;**  выравняет текст в блоке

**margin:auto;**   выровняет сам блок

пример для flex:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.item {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex, cumque.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, с flex обёртка ещё нужна, это меня смутило

Comment: да нее ..это я так сделал ..есть же обычный блок в котором текст ? вот этого и хватит или самого боди предостаточно